# how to make float left over its parent width

Tags: html, css

I don't know what to do now.

I'm creating slider picture. but that problem is I want to make my `<img>` tag to float left for making a slide picture

---

`#broadcast` is represent stage.

`#overflow` is represent mask for overflow picture.

`#inner` is represent for picture container.

`article` is represent for contain each image.

---

I will control slide by using `margin-left` set in the `#inner`. Now I only set article tag to `float` left but it not going as I expected. What should I do sir how to make it align left over its parent width?

```
<div id="broadcast">
    <div id="overflow">
        <div id="inner">

            <article>
                <img src="001.png">
            </article>
            <article>
                <img src="002.ong">
            </article>
            <article>
                <img src="003.png">
            </article>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please post the css aswell

Comment: My Css is not well organize since I set my css from the JavaScript
So that why I have to describe my scenario in detail.

anyway thank for so much @Breezer ^_^.

Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have a fiddle how to get them to align next to eachother and still hide them when they overflow the overflow div, now you just have to use javascript to animate it or some to me complex css ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/8eaQj/

**CSS:**

```
article{
    float:left;
}
#inner{
    height:150px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:1050px;
}
#overflow{
    width:350px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**Html:**

```
<div id="broadcast">
    <div id="overflow">
        <div id="inner">

            <article>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=1">
            </article>
            <article>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=2">
            </article>
            <article>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=3">
            </article>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```